# Copy a layer to a different SRS using GDAL

Tags: shapefile, gdal, coordinate-system, c#

I'm trying to create one shapefile from another existing one. However, I need to have the SRS of the new shapefile different from the existing. The code is in C# and looks as:

```
var layer = inputShapefile.GetLayerByName(_layerName);
var option = String.Format("DST_SRSWKT=EPSG:{0}", WebMercatorWkt);
var options = new[] { option };
outputShapefile.DataSource.CopyLayer(layer, "ShapefileName", options);
```

The code, however, crashes on the last line without throwing any exception etc whatsoever.

Can someone explain how can I use the CopyLayer method to create a new layer in a new shapefile?

Is there any documentation of what options can be provided as part of CopyLayer() method when copying a layer in the shapefile?

Comment: The creation options arenot related to projections and are driver specific,  you can see what options are supported in the [formats documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html). The shapefile options are listed [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html)

Comment: Do you need to reproject the geometry or just redefine the coordinate system? If you need to reproject and you are using gdal 2x look at the gdal VectorTranslate function.

Comment: @Luke: I'm not creating the shapefile in the code above. I created the shapefile already and am now copying a layer into it. I haven't taken a look at _VectorTranslate_ yet. Will see it and get back to you if it works.

Comment: If you're using GDAL 1.x the VectorTranslate function isn't available, you'll have to loop through each feature, reproject the geometry and write it to the output dataset. See https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#reproject-a-layer for an example (in python but the concepts are the same).

Comment: @Luke: I'm not using GDAL 2.X so don't have access to _VectorTranslate_. Will loop through and do one by one. If you want, you may post the comment as answer and detail anything related.